# Wordpress - Output different images instead of category name

Tags: php, wordpress, image, output, categories

On the wordpress theme i am creating, the homepage consists of a list of 6 categories. The format is set out as below -

Cat 1    Cat 2    Cat 3
Cat 4    Cat 5    Cat 6

Instead of wordpress outputting the names of the categories, i would like it to output separate images for each category on the home page only -

Cat 1 IMG    Cat 2 IMG    Cat 3 IMG
Cat 4 IMG    Cat 5 IMG    Cat 6 IMG

How could i achieve this?

*UPDATE*

Currently to output the 6 categories i am using the following line -

```
wp_list_categories('title_li=');
```

But could i possibly add to it to say for example -

*If cat1 id = 1 output img 1*

Could this be possible or is it not necessarily good practice?

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to know how to construct a specific answer to this question unless you describe how you are outputting the categories on your homepage.  If you include that I will update my answer to reflect it.

Two general strategies that occur to me immediately:

**Strategy One**

1. Embed the image in the field for Archive Intro Text for each Category
2. When you loop through the categories to output them on the home page, output the Archive Intro text instead of the title.

**Strategy Two**

1. Use the [Advanced Custom Fields Plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to add an image field to Categories
2. When you loop through the categories to output them on the home page, output the Custom Field instead of the title.

**Strategy Three**

Just use CSS. This is a bit hacky, but depending on your requirements it might be all you want/need. 
First, tnspect the html output by wp_list_categories(). You will notice that each `<li>` has a class like "cat-item-36"

Second, in your css write a rule for each class like that that maps an image to the li.  Like so:
 `.cat-item-36 {
     background: url('url-to-image-you-uploaded-in-the-media-folder');
     height: 80px;
     width: 200px;
  }`

Personally, I'd probably use the **second strategy** since it feels slightly more straightforward and because I often find other good uses for ACF that mean that it is already part of my site.  However, if you don't have any other use for ACF in your site you might want to avoid adding a plugin for a relatively small purpose.